# Imagery from two Landsat 8 paths are visually different

Tags: landsat

I downloaded the Landsat8 L2 imagery for my study area from EarthExplorer. Satellite footprints from two paths cover my study area (image below). But there is a significant visual difference in reflectance of two images despite the dates of acquisition of the imagery are close (5-10 days). Can anyone help fix this?

[image]

Comment: You should use a method called histogram matching. There are special tools for that in products like ERDAS but it may be hard to find an equivalent open source software. Your question feels too large for gis.stackexchange but make a review on histogram matching solutions and come back with focused questions.

Comment: Thanks @user30184, I will let you know.